# Train Text Module in another Idiom

Tags: tensorflow-hub

I was thinking about how train the Universal Sentence Enconder in Portuguese, can you share some tips, what kind of dataset I need for example, transfer learning make a sense?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the TensorFlow-Hub module in a TensorFlow model that trains on Portuguese tasks. So which tasks/data to use is the main question, and that's outside the realm of tensorflow-hub, i.e. you can ask that question and tag it with "machine-learning" and "nlp".

You might also want to take a look at links such as

http://www.nltk.org/howto/portuguese_en.html

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Portuguese+corpus

Comment: Right, and do you know what kind of dataset Google used to train that Sentence Enconder?

Comment: For that you can see the section 3.3 in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.11175.pdf